# Haskell pattern matching - how to use constants variable

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

I would ideally like to write something like this:

```
myValue1 = 1 :: Int
myValue2 = 2 :: Int

myFunc :: Int -> Bool
myFunc myValue1 = True
myFunc myValue2 = False
```

Calling `myFunc myValue2` returns `True` - not what I intend. I know why this happens, but is there a way to express this in Haskell without resorting to C-style `#define` statements?

Comment: Thanks everyone, for the extremely quick responses!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Well, Haskell doesn't unify names like this. Those new 'myValue1' and '2' identifiers are new variables you're binding.

The most Haskelly way is to use strong types and pattern matching:

```
data Values
   = D1
   | D2

myFunc :: Values -> Bool
myFunc D1 = True
myFunc D2 = False
```

Giving you a static guarantee only "1" or "2" can be passed to myFunc, proper symbolic matching and you even retain conversion to integers by deriving Enum.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be the closest to what I want to do - I hadn't thought of deriving Enum, which will be just the ticket.

Answer (score 19):

You cannot match against variable values as Don explained.

But you can use guards in this case:

```
myValue1 = 1 :: Int
myValue2 = 2 :: Int

myFunc :: Int -> Bool
myFunc x
  | x == myValue1 = True
  | x == myValue2 = False
```

Answer (score 7):

If you don't want to create another data type, the usual solution is to use guards:

```
myValue1 = 1 :: Int
myValue2 = 2 :: Int

myFunc :: Int -> Bool
myFunc val | val == myValue1 = True
           | val == myValue2 = False
```

What you put after the pipe can be any boolean condition; if it's true, the corresponding function body will be run.

Answer (score 6):

If the idea is just to define some constants to use in patterns, you can also use the language extension `PatternSynonyms`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE PatternSynonyms #-}

pattern MyValue1 = 1
pattern MyValue2 = 2

myFunc :: Int -> Bool
myFunc MyValue1 = True
myFunc MyValue2 = False
```