# How to define a constant in haskell?

Tags: haskell

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Haskell pattern matching - how to use constants variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3728709/haskell-pattern-matching-how-to-use-constants-variable)

Basically I want something like macros in other language: give literal a name.

I tried to simulate that with function, but `case` expression surprised me:

```
one = 1
two = 2
three = 3

which n =
  case n of
    one -> "one"
    two -> "two"
    three -> "three"
    _ -> "unknown"
```

Compiler warned me that there're overlapped patterns. I realized what the warning really meant after a while and amended the implementation using guards, which worked:

```
one = 1
two = 2
three = 3

which n =
  case n of
    _ | n == one -> "one"
    _ | n == two -> "two"
    _ | n == three -> "three"
    _ -> "unknown"
```

But still, is there a way in haskell to define constants like macros that don't have surprising consequences like what I just saw?

I can use guards in function level but that's not what I asked.

Comment: Yep, my question is duplicated to the link. Thanks @Skurmedel. Hmm, how can I close my question as duplication?

Comment: Also note you can do `{-# LANGUAGE CPP #-}`

Comment: @monadic, indeed! I didn't know this but it is what I'm looking for.